# Call .ashx from jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, httphandler, ashx

I'm developing a mobile application using jQuery. On Microsoft Azure, I have an Asp.Net handler .ashx file. The webpage is http://gloopt.cloudapp.net/Gloopt.ashx.  Basically, the webpage error "Error 1001 Occurred", which I programmed it to return.

When you visit the webpage, you get the error, which is **expected**.  However, if I try to make an Ajax call using jQuery or JavaScript, nothing is returned back.  You can test this by going to http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax2 and putting the url to the ashx file.

I am fairly new to Ajax, so I'm not sure what's going on here.  I've been looking all over the internet, but can't seem to figure out what's wrong.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**
I'm developing a PhoneGap Android Application. That is where I really plan to use this. I will try to test in the application itself. But do you think it will work?

Comment: If I go to your website's home page and add jquery, it works fine: `$.ajax('Gloopt.ashx', { complete: function(resp) { console.log(resp.responseText); } });` prints 'Error 1001 Occurred'

Comment: I apologize for the stupid question. After testing the Ajax call in the PhoneGap Android application, it worked. However, I wasn't aware of the "same origin policy", so I thought the error might be the same in the Android application. I learned something new today. :)

Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you making the ajax call from the same domain, per the same origin policy http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy?

EDIT:
You can see your request being denied using the Console in Firebug http://getfirebug.com/. Install Firebug, browse to the W3School site and run your request. You'll see the request being made and then denied.

Comment: I apologize for the stupid question. After testing the Ajax call in the PhoneGap Android application, it worked. However, I wasn't aware of the "same origin policy", so I thought the error might be the same in the Android application. I learned something new today. :)

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Not a dumb question at all, good luck with the PhoneGap application!

Comment: Thanks! However, I hit some problems, and had to go back to native android development.

Answer (score 2):

An Ajax request in a browser can only call the same host where the page contating the code originated. So you can't call an ashx on cloudapp.net from a page on w3schools.com.

Comment: I apologize for the stupid question. After testing the Ajax call in the PhoneGap Android application, it worked. However, I wasn't aware of the "same origin policy", so I thought the error might be the same in the Android application. I learned something new today. :)

Thank you very much for the help.